# Rewriting MacTypes::FileURL from appscript-ruby to MacRuby ScriptingBridge

Tags: ruby, macruby, scripting-bridge, rb-appscript

I have a script that automatically attaches a given PDF to a publication in [BibDesk](http://bibdesk.sourceforge.net/). Using appscript-rb, the following snippet works perfectly:

```
BibDesk = Appscript.app('BibDesk')
selection = BibDesk.document.selection.get[0]
f = MacTypes::FileURL.path(curfile)
selection[0].linked_files.add(f,{:to =>Selection[0]})
selection[0].auto_file
```

Trying to rewrite it for MacRuby, I came up with the following:

```
framework 'Cocoa'
framework 'ScriptingBridge'

file=NSURL.fileURLWithPath("file:///Users/Stian/Downloads/Telearn.pdf")
dt=SBApplication.applicationWithBundleIdentifier("edu.ucsd.cs.mmccrack.bibdesk")
d= dt.documents[0].selection[0]
d.linkedFiles.add(file,[:to=>dt.documents[0].selection[0]])
```

However, this crashes MacRuby (which I am assuming is also because it is wrong). I just get:

```
 84829 abort      macruby attach_bibdesk.rb
```

How can I rewrite the appscript-ruby into proper MacRuby ScriptingBridge format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should work:

```
 framework 'Cocoa'
 framework 'ScriptingBridge'

 file_path = NSURL.fileURLWithPath("/Users/Stian/Downloads/Telearn.pdf")
 bib_desk = SBApplication.applicationWithBundleIdentifier("edu.ucsd.cs.mmccrack.bibdesk")
 selected_doc = bib_desk.documents.first.selection.first
 bib_desk.add(file_path, to:selected_doc)
```

the file path declaration could be the reason of your problem, but I’m not sure!

Comment: Perfect, thank you _so_ much! What's the to:selected_doc, I've never seen that Ruby construct. Is it like a hash => or?

Comment: the `bib_desk.add(file_path, to:selected_doc)` is a **method with keyword arguments**, this something that comes from Objective-C; it’s not a hash! Ruby 2.0 with have keyword arguments too.  _PS: to find out which methods are applicable to an Object in Macruby you can use `object.methods(true,true) - Object.new.methods` this gives you all objective-C methods you can use_ hope you enjoy Macruby! ;-)